# Node.js + mocha + webdriverjs: Failed tests kill suite

Tags: node.js, webdriver, mocha.js

I am testing a web application using Mocha and [WebDriverJS](https://github.com/Camme/webdriverjs), more or less as decribed [here](http://unexpectedliteral.com/2012/05/09/automated-functional-testing-with-javascript-using-mocha-and-selenium-part-2/). When the tests pass, everything is fine. However, if one test fails, the rest of the tests in the suite will timeout and the runner will exit at the end of the suite, without closing the Webdriver instance. Example test case:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    client = require("webdriverjs").remote({
        logLevel: 'silent'
    });

describe('Self-test', function() {

    before(function(done) {
        client
            .init()
            .url('http://www.wikipedia.org/', function() {
                done();
            });
    });

    after(function(done) {
        client.end(function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    // tests

    it('should fail properly', function(done) {
        client.getTitle(function(result) {
            assert(false, 'This should fail');
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should pass afterwards', function(done) {
        client.getTitle(function(result) {
            assert(true, 'This should still pass');
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

output:

```
~> mocha  test/self-test.js

    Self-test
  1) should fail properly
  2) should pass afterwards
  3) "after all" hook

✖ 3 of 2 tests failed:

1) Self-test should fail properly:
   AssertionError: This should fail
    at null.<anonymous> (./test/self-test.js:24:17)
    at QueueItem (./node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/webdriverjs.js:242:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (./node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/commands/getTitle.js:12:6)
    at QueueItem (./node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/webdriverjs.js:242:15)
    at IncomingMessage.WebdriverJs.proxyResponse (./node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/webdriverjs.js:782:6)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1366:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:402:27)

2) Self-test should pass afterwards:
   Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded
    at Object.<anonymous> (./node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:158:14)
    at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)

3) Self-test "after all" hook:
   Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded
    at Object.<anonymous> (./node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:158:14)
    at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

As far as I can tell, this is because the WebDriverJS queue gets stalled when a test fails. **Is there any way to fix this?** It's sub-optimal even for local command-line testing, and it makes running tests automatically and/or in the background difficult-to-impossible.

**Update:** I think I can fix the queue failure by instantiating a new client for every test, but this would make things much slower (as the WebDriver instance would need to start up from scratch each time) and would leave WebDriver processes hanging around unkilled on test failure. Ideally, I'd like something like the structure offered by [Soda](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda), where a failure somewhere in the queue skips to the end of the queue and then throws the error for the test framework to catch.

Answer (score 2):

You should setup and tear down with `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` instead of `before()` and `after()` if each test is dependent upon the state of WebDriverJS queue.

Comment: The only difference with this approach is that the test hangs after the first test, timing out on `afterEach`, and the second test never runs. The issue is the same.

Comment: What happens when you don't use `after()` and instead just append the `.end()` call to the `client` object in each test? You've essentially stumbled upon async hell between the two APIs, but it should be fixable with some minor tweaks.

Comment: Wish I could help more, but without access to the Selenium server I can't get tests to run.

Comment: It's exactly the same with `.end()` in the test - the WebDriver instance hangs on error, so further queue commands time out. It might work if I actually instantiated a new client at the beginning of every test, but even then the failed WebDriver instances would never terminate properly.

Comment: BTW - I'm just using the standard Selenium server standalone .jar, running locally.

Answer (score 2):

The way webdriverjs is written each test should be a seperate session, and therefore start with init() and end with end(). An exception in your test will bubble up to mocha and mess up the webdriverjs queue. You are therefore trying to us webdriverjs in a way that isn't supported.

Looking at the source code of soda this also seems to be the case. In [client.js:223](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda/blob/master/lib/soda/client.js#L223) exceptions are handled and the error passed back to the callback. This callback is the function set with [.end()](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda/blob/master/lib/soda/client.js#L197) and therefore not having a .end() for every test will simply skip all following tests of the same session until calling the last test's .end() callback.

Is this what you mean by 'a failure somewhere in the queue skips to the end of the queue'? If this is the behaviour you want, you'd have to enclose [webdriver.js:244](https://github.com/Camme/webdriverjs/blob/master/node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/webdriverjs.js#L244) with a try catch and when an exception is caught, call the [.end()](https://github.com/Camme/webdriverjs/blob/master/node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/commands/end.js) command.

Comment: There's no particular reason tests need to be in different sessions, and it makes tests run much, much slower if you write the tests that way (e.g. if your app requires authentication, you need to log in for every test). Even if you did follow this approach, `.end()` would never be called for the current test once one step failed, so you'd still have the problem of unclosed WebDriver instances.

Comment: Wrapping line 244 with `try/catch` would work, but I don't like the "then call `.end()`" option, as it will kill further tests that rely on an open client, and wouldn't throw the error (though I suppose you could perfectly well throw after calling `.end()`).

Comment: Also, calling .end() manually won't work here - that would just add it to the queue, which is probably not running any more. I'd need to call the API command directly, I guess.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I agree. You should probably open an issue on WebDriver and ask for opinions about a better implementation there.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has their own official webdriverjs bindings that run on node now

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

On npm https://npmjs.org/package/selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

you would need a listner to catch the uncaught exception

```
webdriver.promise.controlFlow().on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
     console.error('Unhandled error: ' + e);
     driver.quit();
});
```

this is what i am doing. The only issue with this is it also catches assertion error.
hope this helps.